# Get Inverse Function in a certain domain

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, functions, inverse

I'm trying to make Mathematica giving me the inverse function
of $f$ (below) when restricted to the interval $[v,1]$.

Using `ConditionalExpression` or `Piecewise` as suggested in similar cases does not work.

Result should be the *red* curve in a way that I can apply the numerical derivative.

`v=0.75;
f[x_]:=v ArcSin[x]+Cos[ArcSin[x]];
F=InverseFunction[f];
Plot[{f[x],F[x]},{x,-1.3,1.3},AxesOrigin->{0,0}]`

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Desired picture can be obtained by `ParametricPlot[{{x, f[x]}, {f[x], x}}, {x, -1.3, 1.3}]`, but this in not `InverseFunction`.

Answer (score 1):

A little dowdy but will do for the moment.

`v=0.75;
f[x_]:=v ArcSin[x]+Cos[ArcSin[x]];
F=InverseFunction[f];
ifun=Interpolation[Table[{f[x],x},{x,v,1,0.001}]];
inverse[y_]:=Piecewise[{{ifun[y],f[1]<y<f[v]},{Indeterminate,True}}]
Plot[{f[x],F[x],inverse[x]},{x,-1.3,1.3},AxesOrigin->{0,0}]`

[image]